# ¿Como puedo migrar la base de datos de Prestashop a Mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos, prestashop

Es recomendable migrar bases de datos CMS o crearlas de nuevo para paginas existentes que seran rediseñadas ya no en CMS sino en codigo nodejs

Comment: ¿La [misma pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/609045/migrar-bd-prestashop-a-mysql-o-crear-nueva-desde-cero#comment1073844_609045)?